# New bosses coming to meet with development group, how can we make a good impression?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management, acquisition

The new IT management executives are coming to meet with the small development group we have later today. What is the best way to make a good impression? I thought about writing something funny on the whiteboard we have in the office, but wasn't sure if that would come off the wrong way. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply press buttons, turn knobs and pull levers so it appears as though you are hard at work.

Comment: "I thought about writing something funny on the whiteboard we have in the office, but wasn't sure if that would come off the wrong way." - bad idea.

Comment: You want to impress them with your professionalism not your humor.  Be prepared to go over current projects and the current state they are in, be able to show the processes you have such as source control, automated builds, code review, SCRUM meetings, QA - whatever you are doing that is process oriented and if you have some processes that you would like to implement but your previous management did not want to do, then make a business case for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just be yourselves, there's no need to dress up the office in any way (but by all means tidy things up if they're messy).

You're selling yourselves - it's most important to be able to show your expertise and communication skills.  Be friendly, be knowledgeable.

Comment: This. Don't go all phoney and fill whiteboard, put up stickies, scatter documentation all over tables in a misguided effort to impress. Just be yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Management usually wants you to be productive.

Make sure you seem to be always hard at work. Put some (worn-down) scribbles and schematics on the white board. Have paperwork with handwritten notes and marker lines on your desk. Some coffee mugs help. Stickies (**but not with passwords**!) on the monitor or papers.

Do you know anything about their actual knowledge of development work? If they believe in the caricatures of programmers, have some nerdy stuff around: action figures on top of the monitor.

Don't make it a mess; find a balance between a busy look and cleanliness.

They may also have questions. If you have any idea about those, make sure you can answer them.

And since you don't know the actual moment they will come in: *Now get back to work!*

Comment: You caught me. xD

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you have documentation to support any claims that you are doing quality work. Customer/User emails, timeliness of bug fixes, getting projects done on time, budgets, whatever you have.

Have a summary of current projects and past success stories. If they don't believe you, you'll have other documentation of others indicating they're satisfied with their work.

Get your team together and be prepared to answer the question, "What do you need?" Have a short, well-thought out answer and get some consensus from the team. You don't want everyone throwing up the first thing they think of. You want a dog, ask for a pony.